Problem 5D.4 Isaacs' Finite Group Theory
I have a question about the following problem [Finite Group Theory, Martin Isaacs, Chapter 5]:
Let $ P \in Syl_{p}(G) $ and suppose that $ P \subseteq K \subseteq G $. Show that $ \textbf{O}^{p}(K) \subseteq K \cap \textbf{O}^{p}(G) $ and that if equality holds, then $ \textbf{A}^{p}(K)=K \cap \textbf{A}^{p}(G) $.
I report my reasoning:
By definition, $ \textbf{O}^{p}(K) $ is the unique smallest normal subgroup of $ K $ whose factor group is a $ p $-group. Then $ K/\textbf{O}^{p}(K) $ is a $ p $-group and to prove that $ \textbf{O}^{p}(K) \subseteq K \cap \textbf{O}^{p}(G) $, since $ K \cap \textbf{O}^{p}(G) \lhd K $, just show that $ K/K \cap \textbf{O}^{p}(G) $ is a $ p $-group. I know definitely $ G/K \cap \textbf{O}^{p}(G) $ isn't a $ p $-group but I can't prove what I said.
Can someone help me? However, for the second part of the exercise, I don't know how to proceed.

Since $G/O^p(G)$ is a $p$-group, so is $KO^p(G)/O^p(G)$. Now use the second isomorphism theorem.

Right, thank you. For the second part, I know that $ \textbf{A}^{p}(K) \subseteq K \cap \textbf{A}^{p}(G) $ and for the other inclusion?

Since $O^p(G) \le A^p(G) \le G$ that follows by comparing their orders.

I didn't quite understand what you mean. I only managed to get that $ |K:\textbf{A}^{p}(K)| \leq |G:\textbf{O}^{p}(G) | $

Note also that $P \le K \le G$ implies that $|G:K|$ is not divisible by $p$, so we must have $KO^p(G)=KA^p(G) = G$
